# MVC Action as singleroute without controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've some controllers where i want to show only the action as route. For start i get `Home/Start`. I like to show only `/Start`. For `Contact` as well. Is it only changeable through the routeconfig or is there an attribute?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Start()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Impress()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well how would you distinguish the controllers, if you have 2 actions with the same name? 
And yes, routes are only configurable in your route config-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route config is the only way to do this, here's how

First, define all the non-home controllers routes like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Account", // Route name
    "Account/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter     defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Admin", // Route name
    "Admin/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter     defaults
);
```

Then after all those, define the default route like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter     defaults
);
```

Comment: The change should be added above the default one with a different name or he will never have other controllers.

Comment: Thanks Pedro, I was in the middle of changing that when you commented!

Answer (score 1):

Use AttributeRouting.

You just have to put an attribute with the name of the Action before the action :

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Get")]
    public ViewAction Get(long id)
    {
        return;
    }
```